# Generic user control in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET application, and I want to create a dynamic tab/user control structure for a certain page - so I can dynamically show certain tabs and their user controls.

All controls in this will all have the same properties - JobID and RevisionID. I was thinking about storing this in the ViewState for each control, however I don't want to needlessly repeat the following:

```
public long? JobID { get { return ViewState["JobID"] != null ? (long)ViewState["JobID"] : (long?)null; } set { ViewState["JobID"] = value; } }
public long? RevisionID { get { return ViewState["RevisionID"] != null ? (long)ViewState["RevisionID"] : (long?)null; } set { ViewState["RevisionID"] = value; } }
```

And there may be some methods that I want accessible to all the user controls. What is the best way of achieving this? I'm thinking of either an interface or an abstract class, but I'm guessing I need to be able access the ViewState in the interface/abstract class which I'm having some difficulty with.

Answer (score 1):

If these properties and methods are all leverage by user controls then how about this:

```
public abstract class MyBaseUserControl : UserControl
{
    // shared properties and methods
}
```

and then when building your user controls:

```
public class YourUserControl : MyBaseUserControl
```

The `MyBaseUserControl` can reside in a basic `.cs` file somewhere in the assembly. Further, the only reason I listed the `MyBaseUserControl` as `abstract` is because it's strictly built to be inherited from.